# ASP .NET MVC 4 OutputCache not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I am having a problem with using OutputCache attribute.

I have API which does some calculations:

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 600, VaryByParam = "userId;periodTypeId;dateRange;startData;endDate;", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Any)]
    public JsonResult Calculate(int userId, int periodTypeId, string dateRange, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
      ...
      return Json(answer, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
```

and I want to cache results. But for some reason it's not working. In the response headers I always see "Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate".

API is called from js with jquery ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: callback,
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        ...
    },
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

Maybe I should enable caching on app level somehow?

Comment: what is a url parameter value?

Comment: Here is the url example:
http://localhost:17413/CompensationReports/Calculate?userId=1027&periodTypeId=10&dateRange=current%20week&startDate=11/03/2014&endDate=11/09/2014

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this - if the response from the server includes a Set-Cookie header, it won't be cached.